# Query to get row-related data in columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, subquery

My table in SQL Server that I need to organize into a more readable format:

| BatchAddID | BatchID | Description | Actual |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Chemical 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 1 | Chemical 2 | 11 |
| 3 | 2 | Chemical 1 | 20 |
| 4 | 2 | Chemical 2 | 21 |

What I would like:

| BatchID | Chemical 1 Actual | Chemical 2 Actual |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 11 |
| 2 | 20 | 21 |

How do I get this via a query on the original table?

I tried nesting select statements.

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/3404097) [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help] [mre] PS "efficient" doesn't mean anything in particular.

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please either ask re 1 bad query with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression that it doesn't give what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your goal giving working parts you can do with justification & a [mre]. Then mentioning or showing misunderstood code doesn''t belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

Comment: Moving values to column names is 'pivoting'. (As a straightforward google will tell you.) [tag:pivot] etc etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you always have the same two chemicals "chemical 1" and "chemical 2" then a pivot would work:

```
select 
    BatchID, 
    [Chemical 1] as [Chemical 1 Actual],
    [Chemical 2] as [Chemical 2 Actual]
from
(
    select 
        BatchID,
        [Description],
        Actual
    from 
        dbo.BatchResults
) t
pivot(
    sum(Actual)
    for [Description] in ([Chemical 1],[Chemical 2])
) as pivot_table;
```

Some further detail and information on pivot (including some extra details on making pivots "dynamic" with a dynamic sql approach):

https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-pivot/

Note that personally I would consider your original output as perfectly acceptable "readable format". You may be able leave the details of presentation of data to client code rather than being done in "raw sql" - for example, feeding a pivot table in Excel, a chart or table in a web app, or simply being transformed by some code in a client app.